# When is onTurnDone fired in ngZone

Tags: angular6

I am reading Change Detection in `Angular` and learnt that the application subscribes to `onTurnDone` event from `ngZone` and executes a `tick()` function which does change detection.

When is `onTurnDone` fired? Is it a periodic event which gets fired every few milliseconds or does it get fired when an asynchronous operation happens eg. `click`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/), which monkey-patches most of the Browser APIs(DOM Events, XHR requests, setTimeout...et al) at runtime. These patched methods are then called from within your angular application which in turn call the native browser APIs.
On task completion the zone(Ngzone) fires the onTurnDone(now renamed to [onMicrotaskEmpty](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L385)), which then eventually initiates the change detection process by calling the tick() method.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=237&v=CUxD91DWkGM&feature=emb_logo